# HSQLDB connection error

Tags: java, hsqldb

I created a java program for connect the HSQLDB , the first one works well,

```
public final static String DRIVER = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
public final static String URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:F:/hsqlTest/data/db";
public final static String DBNAME = "SA";
```

but these are not

```
public final static String DRIVER = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
public final static String URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Program Files/tich Tools/mos tech/app/data/db/t1/t2/01/db";
public final static String DBNAME = "SA";
```

the error shows like this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 1 unexpected token: ?
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at HSQLDBManagerImp.getconn(HSQLDBManagerImp.java:48)
    at TESTHSQLDB.main(TESTHSQLDB.java:15)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 1 unexpected token: ?
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ?
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

I googled this connection question , but most of them not help much, someone says that may be the HSQLDB version problem. 
The dbase shut down in "SHUT COMPRESS" model. 
Anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are spaces in between `URL` in second `Relative Path.`

```
C:/Program Files/tich Tools/mos tech/app/data/db/t1/t2/01/db
          ^          ^         ^
```

Use *Single Quotes* `''`.

> *Relative database file paths* can be specified in a
>
> *platform independent manner* as: **'[dir1/dir2/.../dirn/]file-name-prefix'**.

For more reference go to [HSQLDB JDBC](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection.html)